# Creating Multiple Dependent list using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to populate dependant list on the following rows at the column F & G using VBA based on the values in column D, meaning if I have say"A" in row 5 then I need to assign a depend list related to "A" in corresponding F & G columns.

[image]

The below is data for group "A"

[image]

The below is data for group "B"

[image]

Since column "A" is having duplicate data , I am filtering the unique and transposing them into column "E" as headers and using the following code to assign a named range "header" for example to them.

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(7, 5), Cells(7, 7))
    Rng.Select
    Set ws = Sheets("tempdump")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="header", RefersToR1C1:=Rng
```

Then I simulating the "SHIFT+Ctrl+F3" command to assign the first value of each list as the header for that group with the below code.

```
Range(Cells(7, 5), Cells(7, 10)).Select
        Selection.CreateNames top:=True, Left:=False, bottom:=False, Right:= _
        False
```

Now i am going to the previous sheet where i want the dependant list(first image).

In the cell F5 I am creating a dependant list and using the in direct function with the following code.

```
Sheets("Not Filled").Activate


    Cells(7, 8).Select


    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=header"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    Cells(7, 9).Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(F5)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

> I am able to create dependant list based on named ranges using VBA. Everything is fine.
>   The problem starts when i have to do the same thing for group "B"
>   This issue is that since the named range required for group "A" and
>   "B" are 90% identical. ON doing the "Shift+CTRL+F3" action the name assigned to the lists for group B and Group A are same since both header have the same value , this is causing the dependant list to populate values from the list of group A instead of group B.

To be more clear I want the same Header for the first list but the dependant list should be different which is not happening.

[image]

[image]

Ideally the value of the second list should be

- Data_Related
- Incompatible Data
- Obsolete Data
- Corrupted Data

BEEN STUCK HERE FOR PAST two weeks, any amount of help would be massive to me thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear:

The value entered into the AssignedGroup column must change the list of values given to the user using a Data Validation dropdowns in the cause and category columns.

I think I understand what you are doing but I would have done this differently.

Consider:

You need to maintain two lists

List1 has the list of values the user is allowed to enter into the Cause column
List2 has the list of values the user is allowed to enter into the Category column

The values in teh above list depend on the current row and the value entered for the assignedgroup.

So when the user click on a new row or changes a value in the   AssignedGroup column you need to change the values in the lists.  (You would use the worksheet worksheet_change event and workksheet_selectionChange events to manaage this)

So You don't really need to recreate the Validation rules in place on the columns, but the table of underlying values that they pick up.

As Cause is repeated, I woudl write code that maintains a separate table (you might event use a pivot table to do this automatically).  Which just has two columns : AssignedGroup  and Cause.

I think you will be able to take it from here.

Harvey

Comment: Thank you Harvy, I initially thought about that approach but wont that make the sheet slow if for example i have 100 rows?

Comment: Try it I doubt it.   You could write it using excel formulas.  when you select a new row, it updates the value of a single cell.  The tables that give the valid values do a VLOOKUP using this value to create the valid values list.  Your vlookup will need to have IFERROR(VLOOKUP(.....),"")

Comment: I don't think I have the knowledge to do it as you suggest using formulas but anyway thanks for the suggestion appreciate it.